# How to get the results of a stored procedure when using cfscript new StoredProc()

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfml

First time trying to use a stored procedure via cfscript and I can't figure out how to get the results. With a regular query I do something like this to get my result set:

```
queryResult = queryResult.execute().getResult();
```

With the stored procedure my code is:

```
queryResult = new storedProc( procedure = 'stpQueryMyResultSet', datasource = 'mydsn' );
queryResult = queryResult.execute();
writeDump(queryResult);
```

That returns 3 structs - `prefix`, `procResultSets` and `procOutVariables`, but I can't seem to figure out how to get my query results.

Comment: [The documentation](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/script-functions-implemented-as-cfcs/storedproc.html) says *getProcResultSets(): To access result sets returned by the procedure*.  Dump the procResultsSets key and it probably contains an array or structure of query objects.

Comment: You can process a lot of business logic in a stored procedure that you might otherwise try to duplicate in app code. And one of the benefits of sprocs is that they can return multiple result sets if you need to, but you'll have to handle them slightly differently in CF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @Ageax for pointing me to that page.  Here's how I got it working (I also added in a param for max rows to return):

```
queryResult = new storedProc( procedure = 'stpQueryMyResultSet', datasource = 'mydsn' );
queryResult.addParam( type = 'in', cfsqltype = 'cf_sql_integer', value = '10');
queryResult.addProcResult( name = 'result' );
qResult = queryResult.execute().getProcResultSets().result;

writeDump(qResult);
```

Comment: RE: My Comment Above: If you have multiple result sets, you can specify them like `.addProcResult(name='result', resultset=1) .addProcResult(name='result2', resultset=2)`

Comment: And then refer to them as: `qResult=queryResult.execute().getProcResultSets()` then `qResult.result` and `qResult.result2`.